# Weird behavior of header files inclusion

Tags: c++, header

So, i was trying to include a header file in a header file so i dont get linker errors.
But i have encountered a problem:
While i have both Hooks.h and Visuals.h includes placed in one header file, 
Hooks.h works perfectly. No any errors and intellisense doesnt see any.

```cpp
    #pragma once

    namespace Hooks {
        // VMTHook, which was included in the parent header file, works.
        // Moreover, IDirect3DDevice is defined here, same with HRESULT.

        VMTHook D3DDeviceHooks;
        VMTHook CHLClientHooks;
        VMTHook ClientModeHooks;

        /**
        *  Setups all the hooks.
        */
        void SetupHooks() {
            D3DDeviceHooks = VMTHook(g_pD3ddevice);
            CHLClientHooks = VMTHook(g_pClient);
            ClientModeHooks = VMTHook(g_pClientmode);

            Visuals::Hooks::orgEndScene = (Visuals::Hooks::EndSceneFn)D3DDeviceHooks.HookFunction(42, Visuals::Hooks::hookEndScene);
        }
    }
```

But, problems come with Visuals.h.
The includes i had in the parent header file do not work.
The compiler itself throws errors (intellisense does too)

```cpp
    #pragma once

    namespace Visuals {
        namespace Hooks {
            typedef HRESULT(__stdcall* EndSceneFn)(IDirect3DDevice9*); 
            // IDirect3DDevice9 is not defined, same with HRESULT

            EndSceneFn orgEndScene = nullptr;

            HRESULT __stdcall hookEndScene(IDirect3DDevice9* device)
            {
                if (!Visuals::Initialized)
                    Visuals::Initialize(device);

                Visuals::Draw(g_pGlobalvars->frametime);

                return orgEndScene(device);
            }

            WNDPROC orgWndProc = 0;
            // WNDPROC is not defined.

            LRESULT __stdcall hookWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
                if ((msg == WM_KEYDOWN || msg == WM_KEYUP) && (wParam == Visuals::Menu::Variables::MenuHotkey)) {
                    Visuals::Menu::Open();
                }

                return CallWindowProcA(orgWndProc, hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        ...
```

Here is the file in which they both are included:

```
    ... // Has many includes, such as "windows.h" and "d3d9"

    #include "sdk/Definitions.h"

    #include "Utils/PatternScans.h"

    #include "Visuals.h"
    #include "Menu.h"

    #include "VMTHook.h"
    #include "Hooks.h"
```

You can probably issue this by yourself by repeating theese simple steps:

- Create a simple c++ executable project in Visual Studio 2017 (MSVC compiler)
- Create a header file, create 2 more
- Include both theese files in the first header file you made
- Add some includes in the same file, like "stdio"
- Check if stdio definitions exist in both theese files, it should probably be missing in one of them.

By the way, i dont think its a compiler problem, because intellisense shows the same result as the compiler errors do.

Comment: Please don't take screenshots of code, but rather type up relevent portions in the question

Comment: A [mcve] is needed here.

Comment: Copying and pasting is preferable to typing a (likely inexact) copy.

Comment: Does the compiler issue errors? I mean Intellisense can have false positives so the red squiggles could be wrong. Looks like you are needing an include to a windows header in the second picture. Although it could just be a problem with Intellisense. I don't understand why it complains about `LRESULT`

Comment: No one can help you if you don't address the comments above.

Comment: @drescherjm Thats not an intellisense problem. The compiler gives me errors in this file. (C3861; C3080; C2039 and etc)

Comment: Please edit the question and add the exact text of the error messages (I mean text no pictures please!). You can copy that from the Output Tab of Visual Studio. Also you need some type of minimal example.

Comment: @drescherjm The errors are in russian, so i do not think this will be useful here. I will try to translate it though.

Comment: Can you toggle your OS to english? I work with several of people from China and I have them toggle the language on the OS language bar so I can help.

Comment: I recommend to program on an English system. It's much easier to find a solution for your problem if you search for the exact English error message than to search for the error message in your language or to translate it. Therefore many people in my company use an English environment though we are not in an English speaking country.

Comment: @drescherjm I dont think its needed. Theese are simple "defenition is missing" errors.

Comment: @ThomasSablik thanks, i will think about that

Comment: Fixed the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved; All i had to do, is just recreate the Visuals.h file. Should be a compiler error or something else.